# Perl: what's the meaning of .=~

Tags: perl, operators, operator-precedence

In a perl script, I occasionally wrote

```
my $s = "text";
$s .=~ " another text";
print "$s\n";
```

The expected result `text another text` was not printed, instead weird text as `textߞ������ߋ���` was shown in my terminal.

No doubt: the error was the operator `.=~` while indeed, I wanted to write `.=`

But I'm curious: Why isn't `.=~` a syntax error? What's the meaning of this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When choroba isn't around ;) you can use [B::Deparse](https://metacpan.org/pod/B::Deparse) and [ppi_dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/ppi_dumper) to tell you what you're dealing with ( `.=` and `~` )

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e " $foo .=~ /bar/; "
($foo .= (~/bar/));
-e syntax OK


$ ppi_dumper foo.pl
PPI::Document
  PPI::Statement
    PPI::Token::Symbol          '$foo'
    PPI::Token::Whitespace      ' '
    PPI::Token::Operator        '.='
    PPI::Token::Operator        '~'
    PPI::Token::Whitespace      ' '
    PPI::Token::Regexp::Match   '/bar/'
    PPI::Token::Structure       ';'
```

Comment: he is around and recommends the same. I never heard of `B::Deparse`, so your answers result in valuable news - thanks

Answer (score 9):

`.=~` are two operators, `.=` and `~`. The tilde is the binary negation operator, see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators).

Verification:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse,-p -e '$x .=~ $y'
($x .= (~$y));
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: interesting. What is the precedence here? Because `=~` is also used

Comment: @fedorqui: Check the precedence table at the top of the documentation.

Comment: Not sure. I see `left =~ !~` as 6th precedence, whereas `.` appears in the 8th bullet.

Comment: @fedorqui: `~` goes before both of them (5th).

Comment: That does, however, fail to show the constant folding.

Comment: It's not decided by precedence. Precedence only comes into play when you know what token you have. The tokenizer will always find the largest token possible, or else it would never work. So when it finds `.`, and it sees it's followed by `=`, it returns the `.=` operator.

Answer (score 8):

When Perl is doing something you don’t understand syntactically, you either B::Deparse or B::Concise to figure it out.

## B::Deparse

Running

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse
```

on that code yields:

```
my $s = 'text';
$s .= "\337\236\221\220\213\227\232\215\337\213\232\207\213";
print "$s\n";
```

## B::Concise

Running

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec
```

on that code yields:

```
1  <0> enter 
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -:1) v:{
3  <$> const[PV "text"] s
4  <0> padsv[$s:1,2] sRM*/LVINTRO
5  <2> sassign vKS/2
6  <;> nextstate(main 2 -:2) v:{
7  <0> padsv[$s:1,2] sRM
8  <$> const[PV "\337\236\221\220\213\227\232\215\337\213\232\207\213"] s
9  <2> concat[t3] vKS/2
a  <;> nextstate(main 2 -:3) v:{
b  <0> pushmark s
c  <0> padsv[$s:1,2] s
d  <$> const[PV "\n"] s
e  <2> concat[t4] sK/2
f  <@> print vK
g  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
```

In both cases, the answer is the same. You have a literal full of a bunch of weirdo characters. This is the result of compiler applying the unary bitwise negation **`~`** to the literal at compile time, and storing the result in the parse tree.